# find missing element in a javascript object array?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

how would one write a function to find the missing element of an numeric array for example: 
getMissingElement( [0, 5, 1, 3, 2, 9, 7, 6, 4] ) // returns 8

Comment: SO is here to help with existing code, not write code for you.

Comment: What is the definition of a missing element?

Comment: I totally disagree with closing this question. OPs question is clear. If you don't understand the question it's because you don't want to understand the question, as it is clear what the OP wants. And the answers did not have to be full code, could have just as well be logic to send the OP in the correct direction. Giving code is the answerers choice. "too many possible answers"... ? really? Please UPVOTE this question, it deserves it!!... IMHO

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is there just one element missing, and the others are for sure non-repeating?

Then recall that the formula to compute the sum of 0 + 1 + ... + (N-1) is  (N-1)*N/2, and the difference from this to the sum in your array is the missing element:

```
function getMissingElement(array) {
  var sum = 0; 
  var N = array.length + 1;
  for(i = 0; i < N-1; ++i) {
    sum += array[i];
  }
  return (N-1)*N/2 - sum;
}
```

Comment: +1 Good idea. It could be simplified a little bit, though: `var N = array.length`, `for(var i = 0; i < N; ++i)`, `return (N+1)*N/2 - sum`. And this way there is no recalculation of `N-1` at each iteration.

Comment: This is Exceptional. Helped me in other solution with little bit of modification.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getMissingElement(myArray) {
   myArray.sort();
   myAray.reverse()

   for(var i = 1; i < myArray.length; i++) {
       if(myArray[i] - myArray[i-1] != 1) {
           //log your numbers or print them or whatever you like
       }
   }
}
```

This is assuming the most basic definition of "missing item", where the missing item is between existing values on either side.

Answer (score 0):

Here's way to do it:

```
arr.sort(function(x, y){return x - y})
   .map(function(x, i, me){return me[i+1]-x > 1 && x+1})
   .filter(Number)
```

This will give you an array with missing numbers, for `[0,2,4]` it will give you `[1,3]`